# How to use "regsub" or "regex" in Tcl to remove leading and trailing characters from a "start" period

Tags: regex, tcl, regsub

Extracting text parts from a sentence/line using the `regex` and `regsub` functions - left and right. For example the line:

- learning lesson number@12.4.1@_01.html

I need `regsub` and/or`regex` to leave only the snippet between "@".

> Staying like this: **12.1.4** *the rest can erase all the left and right surplus.*

In another scenario, in *Bash* and not *Tcl*. I can do it like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am asking this question, more for the sake of teaching. That is, learning to use the native features of this Tcl language instead of relying on the Unix-Like system command itself.

How can I craft a regular expression to execute this command? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to think in terms of *selecting* the text between the `@` characters. For that, we use `regexp` (with a capturing group). In this case a non-greedy inner piece is easiest.

```
regexp {@(.*?)@} $var -> wantedBit
puts $wantedBit
```

Note that the `->` is a dummy variable name here that takes the whole text of the match (which we are uninterested in).

It is possible to make code that looks more like that sed code with `regsub`:

```
set var [regsub {^.*@(.*)@.*$} $var {\1}]
```

The dialect of regular expressions is slightly different.

Comment: These two code snippets do different things when there are at least three `@` symbols in the input text.

Answer (score 3):

Why the requirement to use a regular expression? This problem can easily be solved without it, using `split` and `lindex`:

```
set var "learning lesson number@12.4.1@_01.html"
puts [lindex [split $var @] 1]
```

Comment: You quoted: _Why the requirement to use a regular expression? [...]_ in your answer. Well, I answer you .. it's not a priority for me, because I even came to imagine doing this simpler way, just did not try! That's the truth. So it was just on my mind. So I thought it would only work with a **regular expression** that matched the given points as "@" references. Only I was wrong, and ugly. Before I had tried something like this -; _simple, fast_ and _functional_. Alias, much easier to decorate and remember.

Comment: I want to make it clear here, to you that .. Although your answer has been clear and easily understood by those who read it. It made it pretty hard for me to decide my Absolute Vote. But taking into account the workload of those who responded first. I used as a criterion for decision making this Vote. They are two too good answers and are within the scope of the question. But I have to decide between an answer of yours and so I decided by the time the answer was given, it was logical reasoning.